# Can the pred() function of sklearn knn classifier take a scipy sparse matrix as an input?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, sparse-matrix, knn

I'm working on a large dataset so I've been storing data in a sparse matrix from SciPy (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html). It takes up less memory space than using numpy array. When I used it in ScikitLearn's KNN classifier, at the step where the pred() function took the sparse matrix as an input, I got the following error:

AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

(Note that you need to set metric='precomputed' in the knn classifier in order to use the sparse matrix.)

However, when I changed the sparse matrix to a numpy array, it just worked. (Suppose the sparse matrix is sp_mat, I just changed it to sp_mat.toarray().) It is fine to use numpy array when I tried with a portion of the data while debugging. But with the entire dataset that I'm using, I'll need to use the sparse matrix. Just wondering if anyone has any idea how to use sparse matrix in knn classifier properly.

Code:

```py
sparse_train = sparse_mat.tocsr()[0:num_train,:].tocsc()[:,0:num_train]  
sparse_test = sparse_mat.tocsr()[num_train:(num_train+num_val),:].tocsc()[:,0:num_train]  
neigh_dist = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=nn, weights='distance', metric='precomputed')  
neigh_dist.fit(sparse_train, y_train)  
y_pred = neigh_dist.predict(sparse_test)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/global/software/sl-7.x86_64/modules/langs/python/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     55     try:
---> 56         return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
     57 

/global/software/sl-7.x86_64/modules/langs/python/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    646         else:
--> 647             raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
    648 

AttributeError: argpartition not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AxisError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-31f5bd405101> in <module>()
----> 1 y_pred = neigh_dist.predict(sparse_test)

/global/software/sl-7.x86_64/modules/langs/python/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/classification.py in predict(self, X)
    143         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
    144 
--> 145         neigh_dist, neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X)
    146 
    147         classes_ = self.classes_

/global/software/sl-7.x86_64/modules/langs/python/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.py in kneighbors(self, X, n_neighbors, return_distance)
    361                     **self.effective_metric_params_)
    362 
--> 363             neigh_ind = np.argpartition(dist, n_neighbors - 1, axis=1)
    364             neigh_ind = neigh_ind[:, :n_neighbors]
    365             # argpartition doesn't guarantee sorted order, so we sort again

/global/software/sl-7.x86_64/modules/langs/python/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in argpartition(a, kth, axis, kind, order)
    806 
    807     """
--> 808     return _wrapfunc(a, 'argpartition', kth, axis=axis, kind=kind, order=order)
    809 
    810 

/global/software/sl-7.x86_64/modules/langs/python/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     64     # a downstream library like 'pandas'.
     65     except (AttributeError, TypeError):
---> 66         return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     67 
     68 

/global/software/sl-7.x86_64/modules/langs/python/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     44     except AttributeError:
     45         wrap = None
---> 46     result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
     47     if wrap:
     48         if not isinstance(result, mu.ndarray):

AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of the code that isn't working?

Comment: The current code appears to accept `csr` format sparse inputs. Try converting, and/or provide the full error traceback.

Comment: @CJR I just added the code and the error to the post. Thanks!

Comment: @BenReiniger I just added the code and the error to the post. Thanks!

Comment: The code you provided runs without error when I simulate some data and put in reasonable numbers for your mystery variables, and the traceback suggests your version of sklearn is considerably older than the current release.

Comment: @CJR You are right! I just updated my scikit-learn from 0.19.1 to 0.24.2 and it works now! thank you!